# Staging, Testing, and Version Control Server Spec Recommendations

Tags: hardware, windows-server-2008

I am going to be working with a few outside developers for some ASP.NET projects and wanted to setup a co-located server for version control, testing, and staging client sites until they are ready to deploy.

I already have the ISP and have a 10 megabit connection burstable to 100, so I don't think bandwidth is going to be an issue.

My question is, what specs should the server itself have? I was thinking of getting a Dell server with the following specs:

- Dual Core Intel Pentium E2180, 2.0GHz, 1MB Cache, 800MHz FSB
- 4GB, DDR2, 800MHz, 4x1GB,Dual Ranked DIMM
- RAID 1 160GB 7.2K RPM SATA 3Gbps hard drives
- Windows Server 2008

Will this suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the project isn't too big that looks fine.  My experience with version control systems on large projects is that memory tends to be the biggest bottleneck.  I'd make sure you can upgrade to 8GB RAM if the project is going to be large.

Comment: tossing in the 8gb memory should just be done with memory costs to help speed up even smaller projects.